# wordpress , вывести повторно sidebar

Tags: wordpress, виджет, sidebar

я пытаюсь вывести sidebar в нескольки блоках

Верхний блок выводит sidebar, но нижний блок - нет, выводит просто пустоту
Почему так? Как вывести в обеих блоках sidebar

```
<div class="medium-3 small-12 columns sidebar">
    <?php
        if(is_page()) {
            //Page Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'page-sidebar';
        } else {
            //Display Default Sidebar
            $wc_sidebar = 'primary-sidebar';
        }

        if(function_exists('is_woocommerce') && is_woocommerce()) {
            //Shop Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'shop-pages';
        }

        if(is_active_sidebar($wc_sidebar)) {
            dynamic_sidebar($wc_sidebar);
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="lightbox-filters-mobile-menu">
    <?php
        if(is_page()) {
            //Page Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'page-sidebar';
        } else {
            //Display Default Sidebar
            $wc_sidebar = 'primary-sidebar';
        }
    
        if(function_exists('is_woocommerce') && is_woocommerce()) {
            //Shop Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'shop-pages';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

во втором блоке вы забыли добавить функцию вывода сайдбара `dynamic_sidebar`.

```
<div class="medium-3 small-12 columns sidebar">
    <?php
        if(is_page()) {
            //Page Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'page-sidebar';
        } else {
            //Display Default Sidebar
            $wc_sidebar = 'primary-sidebar';
        }

        if(function_exists('is_woocommerce') && is_woocommerce()) {
            //Shop Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'shop-pages';
        }

        if(is_active_sidebar($wc_sidebar)) {
            dynamic_sidebar($wc_sidebar);
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="lightbox-filters-mobile-menu">
    <?php
        if(is_page()) {
            //Page Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'page-sidebar';
        } else {
            //Display Default Sidebar
            $wc_sidebar = 'primary-sidebar';
        }
    
        if(function_exists('is_woocommerce') && is_woocommerce()) {
            //Shop Sidebar if single page
            $wc_sidebar = 'shop-pages';
        }
        if(is_active_sidebar($wc_sidebar)) {
            dynamic_sidebar($wc_sidebar);
        }
    ?>
</div>
```